# Force webpage to load at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with a couple of `IFrame` loading through external source code.   I have no control over the external resources.

When the webpage loads it focuses on the one of the `IFrame` instead of focusing at the top of the page.

Here is my simple html page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <div id="topp" tabindex="0"></div>
   </head>
   <div id="topp" tabindex="0"></div>
   <body>
      <p id="test">test 1 2 3 4.</p>
      <br><br>
      <h2>IFrame 1</h2>
      <iframe src="https://..../index1.html" width="100%" height="825px;"></iframe>
      <iframe src="https://..../index2.html" width="100%" height="825px;"></iframe>
      <iframe src="https://..../index3.html" width="100%" height="825px;"></iframe>
      <iframe src="https://..../index4.html" width="100%" height="825px;"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

It's focusing on `Iframe index3.html`, so I have tried to create workaround by including in the page body text some javascript. In this way I can force the page to scroll back to the top as the DOM is being rendered. But it is not working.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Is there a way to find wheter the `IFrame` loads all the SRC, and then focus on top of the page?

Comment: Without knowing the script inside that `<iframe>`, it's quite impossible to figure out what's going on, and prevent it. Could you inspect the contents of that iframe and share with us, please?

Comment: the page has very large html but what I found is that `<body onload="onBodyLoad()">` and it runs some js code and also it loads some dynamic html code as well `document.body.innerHTML ` what exactly you're looking so I can find for that specific

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your JavaScript code with:

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

That line of code will force the page to scroll to the top after loading.

You can add smooth scrolling with this code:

```js
window.scroll({
  top: 0, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth',
});
```

I hope this helps.